# How to extract contents of exe-archive using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, archive, 7zip

I haven an .exe installer, which can easily be opened with 7zip; and it's contents can be extracted without installing.

I'm using pre-compiled 7z.exe and python's `subprocess` to extract it.

```
import os, subprocess
subprocess.call(r'"7z.exe" x ' + "Installer.exe" + ' -o' + os.getcwd())
```

---

However now I'm **looking for a method which will be pure code and doesn't depend on any external executable**, to extract contents of packed exe.

I've tried libraries like `tarfile, PyLZMA, py7zlib` however they fail to extract the exe, or will complain that the file format is not valid, etc.

Comment: Have you done extracting the exe files into the path can you share your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The self-extracting archive is just an executable with a 7zip archive on the end. You could look for all the possible starts of the archive and try decompressing the file handle starting there:

```
HEADER = b'7z\xBC\xAF\x27\x1C'

def try_decompressing_archive(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as handle:
        start = 0

        # Try decompressing the archive at all the possible header locations
        while True:
            handle.seek(start)

            try:
                return decompress_archive(handle)
            except SomeDecompressionException:
                # We find the next instance of HEADER, skipping the current one
                start += handle.read().index(HEADER, 1)
```